# quicksort quickie: the flow of control in quicksort

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, quicksort

In what seems to me a common implementation of quicksort, the program is composed of a partitioning subroutine and two recursive calls to quicksort those (two) partitions.

So the flow of control, in the quickest and pseudo-est of pseudocode, goes something like this:

```
quicksort[list, some parameters]
.
.
.
q=partition[some other parameters]
quicksort[1,q]
quicksort[q+1,length[list]]
.
.
.
End
```

The q is the "pivot" after a partitioning. That second quicksort call--the one that'll quicksort the second part of the list, also uses q. This is what I don't understand. If the "flow of control" is going through the first quicksort first, q is going to be updated. How is the same q going to work in the second quicksort, when it comes time to do the second parts of all those partitions?

I think my misunderstanding comes from the limitations of pseudocode. There are details that have been likely left out by expressing this implementation of the quicksort algorithm in pseudocode.

**Edit 1** This seems related to my problem:

```
For[i = 1, i < 5, i = i + 1, Print[i]]
```

The first time through, we would get **i=1, true, i=2, 1**. Even though *i* was updated to 2, *i* is still 1 in *body* (i.e., Print[i]=1). This "flow of control" is what I don't understand. ***Where is the i=1 being stored when it increments to 2 and before it gets to body?***

**Edit 2**

As an example of what I'm trying to get at, I'm pasting this here. [It's from here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtWw_8VvHjk&feature=relmfu#t=4m30s)

```
Partition(A,p,r)
x=A[r]
i=p+1
j=r+1
while TRUE
    repeat j=j-1
       until A[j]<=x
    repeat i=i+1
       until A[i]>=x
    if i<j
       then exchange A[i] with A[j]
       else return j

Quicksort(A,1,length[A])

Quicksort(A,p,r)
if p<r
    then q=Partition(A,p,r)
        Quicksort(A,p,q)
        Quicksort(A,q+1,r)
```

[Another example can be found here.](http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/quick/quicken.htm)

**Where or when in these algorithms is *q* being put onto a stack?**

Answer (score 1):

`q` is not updated. The pivot remains in his place. In each iteration of quicksort, the only element who is *guaranteed* to be in its correct place, is the pivot.

Also, note that the `q` which is "changed" during the recursive call is NOT actually changed, since it is a different variable, stored in a different area, this is true because `q` is a [local variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable) of the function, and is generated for each call.

**EDIT:** [response to the question edit]

In quicksort, the algorithm actually generate number of `q`s, which are **stored on the stack**. Every variable is 'alive' only on its own function, and is accessible [in this example] only from it. When the function ends, the local variable is being released automatically, so actually you don't have only one pivot, **you actually have number of pivots**, one for each recursive step.

Comment: _The pivot remains in his place. In each iteration of quicksort, the only element who is guaranteed to be in its correct place, is the pivot._ In some implementations ([like this simple version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm)) yes, it is. The one I've pasted to the OP in my second edit (see above) does not do this.

Comment: @andrz: nevertheless, the pivot is still in its place, the only possibility it will move in the posted algorithm, is with another element, which is identical [for the compare function] with the pivot. This is true becasue the pivot is swapped to the `q` place. it means, that all elements left of it are smaller/equal it [there are q-1 elements smaller/equal it] and all elements from the right are bigger/equal it [there are r-q elements equal/bigger], so actually, the place the pivot is in, is its correct place! so assuming quicksort is working, it can be swapped only with an identical element.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Quicksort demands extra memory to function precisely in order to do the bookeeping you mentioned. Perhaps the following (pseudocode) iterative version of the algorithm might clear things up:

```
quicksort(array, begin, end) =
    intervals_to_sort = {(begin, end)}; //a set
    while there are intervals to sort:
        (begin, end) = remove an interval from intervals_to_sort
        if length of (begin, end) >= 2:
            q = partition(array, begin, end)
            add (begin, q) to intervals_to_sort
            add (q+1, end) to intervals_to_sort
```

You may notice that now the intervals to sort are being explicitly kept in a data structure (usually just an array, inserting and removing at the end, in a stack-like fashion) so there is no risk of "forgetting" about old intervals.

What might confuse you is that the most common description of Quicksort is recursive so the `q` variable appears multiple times. The answer to this is that every time a function is called it creates a *new* batch of local variables so it doesn't touch the old ones. In the end, the explicit stack from that previous imperative example ends up being implemented as an implicit stack with function variables.

(An interesting side note: some early programming languages didn't implement neat local variables like that and Quicksort was actually first described using the iterative version with the explicit stack. It was only latter that it was seen how Quicksort could be elegantly described as a recursive algorithm in Algol.)

---

As for the part after your edit, the i=1 is forgotten since assignment will destructively update the variable.

Comment: "the i=1 is forgotten" So you're telling me the first print output is 2?

Comment: I was just saying that after you update the i you lose all trace of the old value, unlike the q in the Quicksort case that is actually a lot of variables with the same name (so the old values still live when you create a new one)

Comment: BTW, thanks for putting up your example. I can understand your version, especially when it's that explicit. I made another edit to the OP with an implementation that is not so explicit. I'd appreciate if you could take another look. Where or when in these algorithms is _q_ being put onto a stack? I don't know why I'm having such a hard time with this! You also mentioned that "my" version requires more memory than the leading brand. What could be improved? (I realize that's a whole 'nother question, but if you've got any links handy, I'd be very appreciative.)

Comment: In my For loop example, the first output I'm getting is "1". So the way I see things, _i_ is initialized to 1, the test yields TRUE, _i_ is updated to 2, and finally we get to the body, Print[i], which for me gives 1! I have no idea where the _i=1_ is being stored for _body_ and after it gets changed to 2. I thought that my understanding of the flow of control in this example is somehow related to the flow of control in the quicksort algorithm I presented.

Comment: 1st comment: you qsort version doesn't need more memory. its just different. 2nd comment: actually its (initialize, test, body, update, test, body, update...) until the test goes false.

Answer (score 0):

The partition code picks some value from the array (such as the value at the midpoint of the array ... your example code picks the last element) -- this is the pivot. It then puts all the values <= pivot on the left and all values >= pivot on the right, and then stores the pivot in the one remaining slot between them. At that point, the pivot is necessarily in the correct slot, q. Then the algorithm sorts the partition [p, q) and the partition [q+1, r), which are disjoint but cover all of A except q, resulting in the entire array being sorted.